# Initial shell item selected on Android but not on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-shell

I'm using the standard Flyout App template in the latest Visual Studio for Mac. When I run it on Android, and expand the flyout menu, the first item is selected:

[image]

When I run it on iOS, it is not:

[image]

Only after selecting another flyout item first, and going back to About, it is selected:

[image]

How can I fix this? Is there a property on `Shell.Current.CurrentItem` I can set?

Our application has an always-visible menu with just the icon, and it's especially annoying that you can't see on which 'tab' you are.

Comment: I had tested it and it seems bug for the ios. In addition, I can find the api to set the selected property by myself. So you can report it to the github.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean you *cannot* find the API - because otherwise I'd interested in what it is (even if it's a private property which I can only set via reflection).

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, it should be can't. I try to set the FlyoutItem's selected or the background color property. But I failed, both the two properties can't be changed programmatically.

Comment: Bug report posted: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15525

Comment: Upgrading to MAUI solved this issue (but introduced a boatload of other unrelated issues ...)